# Set TextView programmatically

Tags: java, android

Here is an xml code of my `TextView`:

```xml
<TextView 
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

I want to add this kind of a `TextView` to my horizontal linear layout programmatically. I am trying this but it says that this code will not work for API lower than Level 11.

```
name_text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
name_text.setText(name);
name_text.setTextSize(15);
```

So what should I do to make it available for all APIs?

Here is a [screenshot of the error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzj4bqZvZBdANHM2VVJESHI1WlE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: All the API calls you're performing are available from API level 1 up. Please add more information, like imports and the exact location of the API level issue.

Comment: yes i mean android api levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong `LayoutParams`. Use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `ActionBar.LayoutParams`.

Comment: To add to this answer, be sure to check your import statements.

Comment: `name_text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`
here is my code ?? I don't have any ActionBar.LayoutParams in it

Comment: You have imported the wrong LayoutParams. Like @Code-Guru pointed out: Check your import statements.